# PDFBox 2.0.19 release date

Tags: release, pdfbox

I'm currently using 2.0.18 and facing this bug:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4741?jql=project%20%3D%20PDFBox%20AND%20description%20~%20%22PlainText*%22%20%20ORDER%20BY%20lastViewed%20DESC

Any release date expected for the fix?

Comment: Why not ask in the issue itself? (Although we can't say, releases are every 3-4 months). In the meantime, use a snapshot https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.19-SNAPSHOT/ , or do a workaround by setting the contents.

Comment: I agree with Tilman. Ask this in the issue tracker of PdfBox. You can even do some stuff there e.g. add yourself as a watcher to get informed or vote for it... Stackoverflow is not the place to ask about release dates...